# Combine 2 models into one array, paginate, and force 1 partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I want to combine data from two different models, combine it into one array and use the will_paginate gem to paginate the results in my view on that collection. I'm already using `require 'will_paginate/array'` to allow for a normal, non-ActiveRecord array and its all working properly.

My problem is that its using two different partials to render the entries based on which model the data originated from. How do I force it render one specific partial?

**controller**

```
def sample_action
  page = params[:page] || 1

  @collection = []
  @car.messages.select {|msg| @collection << msg}
  Alerts.where(car_id: @car.id).select {|alerts| @collection << alerts}

  @collection = @collection.sort{|a,b| b[:created_at] <=> a[:created_at]}
  @collection = @collection.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => 30)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :sample_action }
  end
end
```

**view**

```
<% if @collection.count > 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="car-alerts" class="car-alerts-all">
        <%= render @collection -%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @collection -%>
<% else %>
  <p class="no-alerts-message">Your car is healthy</p>
<% end %>
```

**car partial**

```
Car - <%= collection.id %>
<br>
```

**alert partial**

```
Alert - <%= collection.id %>
<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the fact that you basically just want to output the model name and do this:

```
<% if @collection.count > 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="car-alerts" class="car-alerts-all">
        <%- @collection.each do |obj| -%>
          <%= obj.class.to_s -%> - <%= obj.id %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @collection -%>
<% else %>
  <p class="no-alerts-message">Your car is healthy</p>
<% end %>
```

but it would break easily if you wanted to add labels different to class names.

Comment: I didn't think of taking it out of the partial altogether but that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each item in the collection and have a conditional based on the model type, so for example:

```
<div id="car-alerts" class="car-alerts-all">
  <% @collection.each do |car_or_alert| %>
    <%= 
    if car_or_alert.is_a?(Alert)
      render :alert #you need to add locals here as well, but it unclear what locals you are using
    else
      render :car #see above
    end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about doing it that way but was worried about it getting a little messy. Definitely one way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as setting the partial from `render`

```
<% if @collection.count > 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="car-alerts" class="car-alerts-all">
        <%= render collection: @collection, partial: 'car/partial_name' -%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @collection -%>
<% else %>
  <p class="no-alerts-message">Your car is healthy</p>
<% end %>
```

This being the key change -

```
<%= render collection: @collection, partial: 'car/partial_name' -%>
```